# Routing a particular subnet into a VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, openvpn

My network looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying configure my router so that the subnet (192.168.2.0/24) is routed over the VPN tunnel (tun0) on the gateway/router.

While at the same time clients on the subnet (192.168.1.0/24) are routed directly out over ppp0, ie not through the VPN.

I don't want to run VPN software clients, and certain clients on the network need direct access. eg a windows gaming computer, voip phone etc.

My router also runs an unbound DNS server that forwards DNS lookups to dnscrypt-proxy.

The network interfaces on the router are configured like:

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

auto lo:1
iface lo:1 inet static
    address 127.0.0.2
    netmask 255.0.0.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Virtual interface
auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252

auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet ppp
    pre-up ip link set dev eth1 up
    provider <isp>
    post-down ip link set dev eth1 down
```

For the moment I'm using a virtual interface ie eth0:2. I am also wondering if this is appropriate or should that be a VLAN ie eth0.2?

As far as I was aware the only difference would be that clients would then require a VLAN interface eg:

/etc/systemd/network/MyEth.network

```
[Match]
Name=enp10s0

[Network]
DHCP=v4
DNS=192.168.2.1
Address=192.168.2.30/24
Gateway=192.168.2.1
VLAN=vlan2
```

/etc/systemd/network/MyEth.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan2
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=2
```

and be unable to cross over subnets eg 192.168.1.10 would be unable to talk to 192.168.2.10.

The iptables rules I've attempted to get this working with are as follows:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

export WAN=ppp0           # Link to ISP
export INT_IF=eth0        # Interface that serves internal network
export EXT_IF=eth1        # Interface between router and modem
export WAN_TUNNEL=tun0    # VPN tunnel created by OpenVPN
export VPN_VLAN_IF=eth0:2 # Interface internal clients have as their gateway

# Allows internet access on gateway
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

#############
# NAT Rules #
###############################################################################
# VPN
iptables -I FORWARD -i ${VPN_VLAN_IF} -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${VPN_VLAN_IF} -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${WAN_TUNNEL} -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o ${WAN_TUNNEL} -j MASQUERADE
###############################################################################

###############################################################################
# NO VPN
iptables -I FORWARD -i ${INT_IF} -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${INT_IF} -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ${WAN} -j MASQUERADE
###############################################################################

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do echo 1 > $f ; done

/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

I also expect that I would need to use route-nopull in my openvpn configuration, otherwise everything on the gateway would be routed over the VPN?

By default when I connect to the OpenVPN server I see:

```
openvpn[3469]: /sbin/ip route add <ip_of_vpn> dev ppp0
openvpn[3469]: /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 172.16.32.1
openvpn[3469]: /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 172.16.32.1
```

which results in a route like:

```
ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 172.16.32.1 dev tun0 
default dev ppp0  scope link  metric 300 
<ip_of_vpn> dev ppp0  scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 172.16.32.1 dev tun0 
172.16.32.0/20 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.39.64 
192.168.0.0/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1 
<ip_from_isp> dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X
```

Would I need a static route to route 192.168.2.0/24 to the VPN ie to tun0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using a custom routing table and policy (I recently did something very similar myself)

1. Firstly create a custom routing table for your VPN

   ```
   echo "10 vpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   ```
2. Tell iproute2 to use this routing table for traffic to and from your 192.168.2.0 network

   ```
   ip rule add from 192.168.2.0/24 table vpn
   ip rule add to 192.168.2.0/24 table vpn
   ```
3. Set up NAT masquerading for the 192.168.2.0 network

   ```
   iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0:2 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
4. Enable IP forwarding if it's not enabled (required for NAT)

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
5. In your OpenVPN config add the following lines

   ```
   #Prevents default gateway from being set on the default routing table
   route-noexec
   #Allows route-up script to be executed
   script-security 2
   #Calls custom shell script after connection to add necessary routes
   route-up /etc/openvpn/route-up.sh
   ```
6. Create a custom shell script in /etc/openvpn/route-up.sh and chmod +x it

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   #Clear all routes on vpn routing table (this is to make sure there isn't any crap left over from a previous vpn connection
   /sbin/ip route flush table vpn

   #Copy routing table from main routing table into vpn table
   /sbin/ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table vpn $ROUTE; done

   #Add default gateway to vpn routing table
   /sbin/ip route add default via ${route_vpn_gateway} dev ${dev} table vpn
   ```

Steps 2 and 3 will not persist across reboots so you will need to add those parts to your init scripts as required.

Comment: tried with openwrt and a mwan setup, didn't work. i suspect mwan rules to mess up with this