# linux routing - how to switch PCs between multiple gateways

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, gateway

I have a linux router with multiple gateways (cable modem, ppp, vpn, etc). What's the best way to forward all internet traffic for individual users through different gateways?

Here's an example:
[Network diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP2nh.png)

It seems I need to create individual routing tables for each connection, add connection GW, add the connection IP, add user IP(s), and enable NAT. This works with PPP, but not with OpenVPN (default config, my router is the client).

e.g.:

```
openvpn --route-nopull --config ~/connect.ovpn &
ip route add default via 10.8.0.5 table myvpn
ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5 table myvpn
ip rule add from 10.8.0.6 table myvpn
ip rule add from 192.168.1.3 table myvpn
ip rule add from 192.168.1.4 table myvpn
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o myvpn -j MASQUERADE
```

In this example, the router it's self can connect through 10.8.0.6 (or any other connection individually) but clients can not.

Comment: # route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 cable
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cable
x.x.x.26     10.10.10.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 cable
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lan

x.x.x.26 is the openvpn server

Comment: # ip rule list
0: from all lookup local 
32764: from 192.168.1.3 lookup myvpn 
32765: from 192.168.1.4 lookup myvpn
32766: from 10.8.0.6 lookup myvpn 
32767: from all lookup main 
32768: from all lookup default

Comment: # iptables -t nat -v -L POSTROUTING -n --line-number
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 37 packets, 2856 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      myvpn  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Routing a particular subnet into a VPN tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/887745/routing-a-particular-subnet-into-a-vpn-tunnel?rq=1)

It can be adapted to my situation or similar. Note the clever route-up.sh to copy routes into a new table on startup.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN tunnel between the machines on your local network and the router with multiple gateways is total overkill.

Instead, use [VLAN tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) to split your LAN into multiple "overlays" (the different colors in your network diagram), make sure each user/machine is connected to the correct VLAN, and configure your router to route each VLAN to the appropriate gateway.

Each VLAN will appear as a network adapter on its own on the router. Assuming the router is some kind of embedded Linux, you can then easily use [policy routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) to integrate the egress network interface into the routing decisions. It's usually not necessary to use `iptables` for that, unless you want a firewall (though for some reason lots of people on the internet seem to want `iptables` for routing... which is one of my pet peeves).